# How to drop a file from explorer and get it's full path to electronjs app

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am using electron forge with typescript integration.

I can't find a solution to drag and drop files from explorer and get their full paths

I put in index.ts the following:

```
import {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} from 'electron';

ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filepath) => {
    console.log("ondragstart " + filepath); // doesn't work
});
```

but doesn't show anything when I drag n drop files

any ideas?

Comment: And do you define `ondragstart` in your renderer process by sending the filepath using `ipcRenderer`? That event won't appear out of thin air. Take a look at [Electron's file d'n'd example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/how-to/native-file-drag-drop), maybe that'll help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to grasp some concepts:

- [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop)
- [Sending Messages](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) using `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`

Action happens on the `renderer` which gets the dropped files using `HTML5 FIle API` and passes *file paths* to `main` using `electron's IPC`.

#### renderer.js

```js
document.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

document.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    let pathArr = [];
    for (const f of event.dataTransfer.files) {
        // Using the path attribute to get absolute file path
        console.log('File Path of dragged files: ', f.path)
        pathArr.push(f.path); // assemble array for main.js
    }
    console.log(pathArr);
    const ret = ipcRenderer.sendSync('dropped-file', pathArr);
    console.log(ret);
});
```

#### main.js

```js
let winmain;

function createWindow () {
    winMain = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    winMain.loadFile('index.html');
}



ipcMain.on('dropped-file', (event, arg) => {
    console.log('Dropped File(s):', arg);
    event.returnValue = `Received ${arg.length} paths.`; // Synchronous reply
})
```

Comment: thanks for your very clean and working solution!